# Prove that $\text{Var}(AX+b)=[A\Bbb E(X)+b]^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, variance, random-matrices

Prove the identity in the title where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix of constants, $X$ is an $n\times 1$ random vector and $b$ is an $m\times 1$ constant vector.

I'm aware of the proofs for $E(AX+b) = AE(X)+b$    and    $\text{Var}(AX)=A\text{Var}(X) 
A^T$, I just haven't seen a way to apply their logic here. Applying $Var(X)=\Bbb E(X^2)-[\Bbb E(X)]^2$ and expanding $[A\Bbb E(X)+b][A\Bbb E(X)+b]$ didn't lead me toward any other ideas either, since the dimensions of the matrix and vectors didn't allow further operations.

---

Update:

It seems that there was a printing error and this proof does not exist, as angryavian suggested.

Comment: What are $X^2$ and $[E(X)]^2$? Those make sense when $X$ is a square matrix, but I am not sure how it is applied here. Is $$X^2 = \begin{pmatrix}x_0^2 \\ x_1^2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n^2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I am not familiar with this topic, so I looked it up. It appears that for column vectors, $$\text{Var}(X) = E\big[(X-E[X])(X-E[X])^T\big]$$ Does this help?

Comment: Are you sure the result is correct? The covariance matrix of $AX + b$ should be $A \operatorname{Var}(X) A^\top$ since shifting by $b$ does not affect variance or covariance.